# Prevent React Route to re-run componentDidMount() on traversing back on same route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

For a given route `localhost:3000/my-link`, component `MyLink` is rendered.
In `MyLink` component, ajax request is fired in `componentDidMount()` which then sets the `state` object of the `MyLink` class and renders the component.

But when navigating to some other route and switching back to `/my-link` ajax is fired again. In short, whole state previously populated is lost. Can there be a way to check if the previous `state` is already populated, then prevent `componentDidMount` to be called?

Comment: Consider using local caching like session storage

Comment: can redux of any other lifeCycle hook will be helpful?

Comment: Redux may help, yes. You still need to check if the data exists in state to see if the Ajax needs to be called.

Answer (score 0):

`componentDidMount()` is invoked immediately everytime a component is mounted in the DOM. What you're trying to do can be achieved by integrating react redux store. Call the Ajax call according to store state variable. On firing the AJAX requests Dispatch the action to make the variable true.

```
componentDidMount() {
        if(!this.props.variable)
        {
            //AJAX CALL
            dispatch({ type: 'SET_VARIABLE', value: true });
        }
}
```

Once it sets to true, it won't be called next time you navigate to this route.

Answer (score 0):

When you switch from your existing route `localhost:3000/my-link` to any other page like `localhost:3000/other-link`, Your `MyLink` component got unmounted but at the same time, your data fetched in `MyLink` component is still in your redux store.

Here's what you can do;

1. If the data which you are fetching in `MyLink` is frequently changing then it is a good idea to fetch it again when you visit the same link again. Means, You need to clear the state when your component unmounts.

   ```
   componentWillUnmount() {
     // resetData is an action which will clear the data in your MyLink reducer.
     this.resetData();
   }
   ```

So, When you visit the same link again, The component won't have any previous data and it will fetch the fresh data.

2. If that data is not frequently changing and you're okay with getting it just one time then you can make a conditional call to your action.

```
    componentDidMount() {
      // this.props.data is a state from redux store.
      if(!this.props.data){
          this.getData();
      }
    }
```